# How to align qed symbol with centered text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am using the following proof environment:

`\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=9pt, 
spacebelow=9pt,
headfont=\it \bfseries,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=6pt,
qed=\qedsymbol,
headpunct=
]{mypf}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=Proof, style=mypf]{pf}`

If I centre text in the last line, the qed symbol is put on the line after. How do I fix this? For example,

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=0pt, 
spacebelow=8pt,
headfont=\it \bfseries,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=6pt,
qed=\qedsymbol,
headpunct=
]{mypf}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=Proof, style=mypf]{pf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pf} Let $w \in W$. Then we have 
$$  \ell (w)-1=\ell (w)-\ell (s_i) \leqslant \ell (ws_i) \leqslant \ell (w)+\ell (s_i)=\ell (w)+1.
$$
\end{pf}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that illustrates the problem.  A minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  That way people know, for example, which packages you're using in your document.

Comment: Don't use the plain TeX construct `$$ … $$`, use  LaTeX  `\[ … \]` instead. Also, try with `\qedhere `.

Comment: @Bernard That doesn't work either

Comment: I don't know well enough the internals of `amsthm`, but it is automatic with `ntheorem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\qedhere`, and ***don't*** use `$$` under any circumstances.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % sorry, I can't stand it
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=0pt, 
spacebelow=8pt,
headfont=\it \bfseries,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=6pt,
qed=\qedsymbol,
headpunct=
]{mypf}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=Proof, style=mypf]{pf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pf} Let $w \in W$. Then we have 
\[
\ell (w)-1=\ell (w)-\ell (s_i) \leqslant \ell (ws_i) \leqslant \ell (w)+\ell (s_i)=\ell (w)+1.
\qedhere
\]
\end{pf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I find sans serif text and serif math a really bad combination, so I commented the relevant line. If you really want that, uncomment the line.